# How to load data in to rowData in ag-grid?

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid

I have the following code in my html-class:

```
<ag-grid-aurelia #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" #agGrid  grid-ready.call="onGridReady()"
                             grid-options.bind="filesThatAreMalwareOptions">

                <ag-grid-column header-name="date" field="date" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="fileHash" field="fileHash" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="fileName" field="fileName" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="fileSize" field="fileSize" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="mimeType" field="mimeType" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Malware" field="Malware" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Virustotal-Link" field="Virustotal-Link" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
</ag-grid-aurelia>
```

And the following code in my TypeScript-class:

```
filesThatAreMalwareOptions:GridOptions = {
      rowData:  []      
    };
```

```
getValueFromRequest(queryEndpoint){
        this.http
            .fetch(queryEndpoint, {
                mode: "cors"
            })
            .then(result => result.json()
            ).then(body => {
            if (queryEndpoint == "TestFileData"){
                this.filesThatAreMalwareOptions.rowData = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            });
```

If I want to load the data from the endpoint of my service the gird display "No rows to show". If I hardcode the rowData like:

```
filesThatAreMalwareOptions:GridOptions = {
      rowData:  [ {date: '02.04.1990', fileHash: 'X', fileName: 'X', fileSize: 3245, mimeType: 'PDF'}]
};
```

The data is displayed in the grid. Where is the problem with loading the data from the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the property rowData directly, you will need to use an api call:

```
this.filesThatAreMalwareOptions.api.setRowData(JSON.parse(body));
```

See the api reference:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/